# 2011 Moderator Election - Town Hall Chat:  Wednesday 9/21 8pm UTC / 4pm EDT

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the [moderator elections](https://security.stackexchange.com/election/1), we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.  I am working with the candidates to find a time that allows the most participation.

**The Town Hall Chat will take place Wednesday the 21st at 8pm UTC / 4pm EDT.**

**[view in other timezones](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=9&day=21&year=2011&hour=20&min=0&sec=0&p1=0)**

**[register here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1380/security-town-hall-chat?tab=schedule)**

---

Here are the details so far:

- I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the election phase. I'm operating on the assumption that there won't be a primary phase.  This means that I am looking at the 21st-23rd. As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates to find a best fit based on availability, I will edit this post with details on the "when".
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=security.stackexchange.com).
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidates regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, a digest of the event will be permanently linked here.

Comment: any of those 3 days should work for me. Timing-wise I have most flexibility on timing after 1900 GMT+1

Comment: I prefer between 15:00 GMT and 22:00 GMT. But I am pretty flexible, except that I cannot attend between 08:30 GMT - 15:00 GMT on Wednesday.

Comment: As my previous email to you noted, your announced time works for me - thanks.  But I'm worried to see it seems to conflict for @Hendrik.  Were there no times without conflict?

Comment: @nealmcb - that time fits in with Hendrik's times, so hopefully will be fine

Comment: @rory Ahh - thanks.  The first time I saw that "8pm UTC" I remember thinking that I'd never seen UTC times that weren't using 24-hr notation.  And the second time around I just totally ignored the "pm" part, so I thought there was a conflict....